# How do I write a table with 2 primary keys in springboot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

First of all I'm sorry if I made a mistake this is my first question

I have to merge Contact table with Staff and Covid table.

Contact.java

```
public class Contact implements java.io.Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private ContactId id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "covidId",insertable = false,updatable = false)
private Covid covidContact;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "staffId",insertable = false,updatable = false)
private Staff staffContact;
}
```

ContactId.java

```
public class ContactId implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "covidId",insertable = false,updatable = false)
private int covidId;

@Column(name = "staffId",insertable = false,updatable = false)
private int staffId;

}
```

I wrote this but I can't get the correct result.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQutE.png)

What's wrong? Can you help me?

[Table diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnKUp.png)

Comment: If you are eclipse, ty JPA to generate entity class from tables which will do the trick. No need to write manually these classes. Refer this link for details. https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks006.htm

Comment: I don't think  your problem is with the primary key, looks like your problem is with the json serialization/deserialization. Do you have any error stack traces?

Comment: @Krishna I'm using intellij

Comment: @AleksanderNdoci Nope

Comment: can you post the request/response json?

Comment: A sql table can only have one primary key (as the name suggests). It can consist of multiple columns. Additional keys are just (optionally unique) indexes

Answer (score 0):

Try to add @Embeddable annotation to ContactId class and All/No args constructors